# Inner joins in Ebean?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I read https://archive-avaje-org.github.io/ebean/introquery_joinquery.html  looking at Example A, I noticed there's no specification of the inner join common column.  I think their fetch-tablename syntax causes Ebean to look at what column the 2 tables have to inner join on.  Then they are storing each result as an Order?  They are joining 2 tables, so how can they store columns from the customer table as an Order?

I tried to do an inner join with ebean in my code and discovered at least one of my assumptions was wrong.  I have 2 tables, a Street table and a House table(one to many relationship).  The street_id column in the House table is the foreign key to the id column of the Street table.  I'm trying to come up with the Ebean equivalent of this sql:

```
SELECT s.name, h.owner, h.isSubscriber FROM Street as s INNER JOIN House as h WHERE     
h.street_id=s.id AND h.isNew='false'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you just reference the table directly in the `where` ExpressionList to require an inner join, something like:

```
Ebean.find(House.class)
     .select("street.name, owner, isSubscriber")
     .where()
     .eq("street.id", s.id)
     .eq("isNew", false)
     .findList();
```

This assumes that you have a House Entity setup similar to this:

```
@Entity 
public class House extends Model {

    @Id 
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Street street;

    ...
}
```

And a Street Entity like this:

```
@Entity 
public class Street extends Model {

    @Id 
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "street")
    public List<House> houses;

    ...
}
```

Comment: What is "s.id" in the "Ebean.find"? How using ".eq("street.id", s.id)" will Ebean join House and Street on house.street_id = street.id?

Comment: "s" is the Street parameter provided at this point, and it's simply referencing the Street's id field.